# How to get rid of premium SSD managed disk for persistent storage?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

This question is related to cluster configuration and storage cost. I've read the updated article on [selecting the correct SKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/manage-cluster-choose-sku). I used to run my cluster on Eav4/Easv4 Series nodes which use premium SSD managed disk for storing data in the hot cache. I decided that I do not want to use that feature and instead I selected the Eadsv5 Series which does not support premium storage. I made the change in July but I still see that I'm paying for the P30 premium SSD managed disk in August. I've set the hot data cache period to 1 day.

Questions that arise are:

- Will the data be migrated from these managed disks to Azure Storage when selecting a different SKU?
- Why am I still paying for the premium SSD managed disk?
- Is it a remnant from my previous cluster configuration and if so, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: "Azure Data Explorer leverages Azure Storage as its durable persistence layer" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/business-continuity-overview#persistence-layer Please open a support ticket

Comment: Thanks David, but could you please elaborate on why I need to open a support ticket? Am I mistaken in saying that the P30 premium SSD managed disk is used for persistence?

Comment: **(1)** Didn't you say that although you switched to another SKU, it seems that you are still paying on a component that is part of the old SKU? **(2)** There are multiple levels of storage: RAM, SSD & Azure Storage. There are different retention policies for SSD & Azure Storage. Data might exist on Azure Storage but not on SSD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/cachepolicy

Comment: 1. Yes, that is my interpretation. But do you know whether that is even a possible error condition in ADX? I just checked the invoice for Saturday and the cost for the P30 managed disk is not there, which would indicate that they are not being used for persistent storage. I power the ADX down during weekends. Does that mean that they're used for something else?

I will check todays bill on upcoming Wednesday to see if the P30 managed disk is still present.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz - The bill for yesterday shows the P30 SSD managed disk when I started to run the cluster again and ingest with a 1 day hot cache period. I guess I can conclude from this that it is not used for persistent storage. Still, I'm confused by the fact that the cluster is using premium SSD storage and the adsv5 Series VM combined. I suppose it is out of my control and will leave it at that.